# Generating Triangles at a Mouse Press

Tags: javafx, polygon

I'm trying to generate random shapes based on a mouse press. All my shapes are working except for my triangle. I used Polygon and an array to create it. However, it keeps adding more points to the array, so it distorts the the triangle when I try to generate another triangle. I tried to clear out the array, but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
      case "t":
                Double[] array;

                t.setFill(Color.rgb(fill, fill2, fill3));

                t.getPoints().addAll(array = new Double[]{
                    (double)coordinate, (double)coordinate2, 
                    (double)coordinate3, (double)coordinate4,
                    (double)coordinate5, (double)coordinate6});

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = null;
                }

                pane.getChildren().add(t);

                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you want to create a new triangle, you have to actually create a new triangle. To do this you must call `new Polygon()`, which you aren't currently doing.

```
case "t":
    Polygon t = new Polygon();

    t.setFill(Color.rgb(fill, fill2, fill3));
    t.getPoints().addAll(new Double[]{
      (double)coordinate, (double)coordinate2, 
      (double)coordinate3, (double)coordinate4,
      (double)coordinate5, (double)coordinate6}
    );

    pane.getChildren().add(t);

    break;
```